# Onchange not firing for file upload "proxy"

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I'm trying to use this drag and drop image uploader:

https://www.codingnepalweb.com/drag-drop-file-upload-feature-javascript/

It works when I drag and drop but not when I use the Browse button.

The "interesting" part is this part:

```
button.onclick = ()=>{
  input.click(); //if user click on the button then the input also clicked
}
```

and the button and input themselves

```
<button>Browse File</button>
<input type="file" hidden>
```

The function is to be invoked onchange:

```
input.addEventListener("change", function(){
  file = this.files[0];
  dropArea.classList.add("active");
  showFile(); 
});
```

My problem is that clicking on the button does open the file browser but when selecting an image, the on change is not fired (because for some reason the input/file doesn't change). I tried unhiding the input and use that instead and when doing so, it works.

How do I get the button to work as intended so that selecting an image registers it to the input/file control?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use the `hidden` attribute, hide the input field using a method like this instead: https://www.nomensa.com/blog/how-improve-web-accessibility-hiding-elements

Comment: FYI, rather unnecessary to add a click handler to a button, when you make the button a `label` instead (and properly associate it with the input field using the `for` attribute.)

Comment: @CBroe good point and valid solution. Changing the button tag to a label made the whole thing work. Thanks :) Maybe you could make it an answer instead.